# How to remove the character '%' from string in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a nvarchar column in a table that contains the character % in its text. I want to remove or substring this character from this text. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific `remove` function, but maybe you can `replace` it with nothing.

Comment: You cant expect to get help if you tried nothing.

Comment: Have you tried the replace function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a string in a SQL Server Table Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814548/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-sql-server-table-column)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you strip a character out of a column in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983417/how-do-you-strip-a-character-out-of-a-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove certain characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319141/remove-certain-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = REPLACE(ColumnName,'%','')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it from the query, then you can do this

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(columnName, '%', '') AS TrimmedValue
```