# SQL Server: Remove character '.' and '@' from string select a set of words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an email id as Input:

```
 pqr.xyz@abc.com
```

How to remove'`.`', '`@`' and select string before '`@`' and 1st letter after '`@`' after this make everything in uppercase

Required Output:

```
PQRXYZA
```

Comment: ok, what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove certain characters from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319141/remove-certain-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query:

```
select UPPER(Replace(Replace(Left(fieldname, Charindex('@', fieldname) + 1), '.', ''), '@', ''))
```